# Why can't Xcode find my App for Unit Tests?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

I'm fairly inexperienced in iOS. I wanted to write Unit Test for my Cocoapods Project. 
[image]

My ViewControllers that I want to test are in Pods. When I want to write a unit test, I  already receive an error message with 
`import MyApplication`

which says

`No such module 'MyApplication'`

Note that I used "MyApplication" only as a substitute for orginal name I crossed out in red in the picture.

What is the issue?

EDIT:

code of my test class:

```
import UIKit
import XCTest
import Pods_MyApplication_Example

@testable import Pods_MyApplication

class Tests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testExample() {
        // This is an example of a functional test case.
        XCTAssert(true, "Pass")
    }

    func testPerformanceExample() {
        // This is an example of a performance test case.
        self.measure() {
            // Put the code you want to measure the time of here.
        }
    }

}
```

To create a test target, on the test navigator, I click on the '+' and then choose 'New Unit Test Target'

[image]

I am sorry if there are any information missing. I will add those if there are any!

EDIT2: Changed picture which might provide more information

Comment: What is the Pods_MyApplication_Example module that you're importing? What happens if you remove the import Pods_MyApplication_Example line?

Comment: Thanks for the comment and sorry for the late response. MyApplication_Example is a target of MyApplication. However removing that import line doesn't resolve the error message.

Comment: MyApplication_Example is the app target. That's what you have to supply in @testable import. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `@testable import` to import your app's module for unit testing. You have to supply the name of your application target, Pods_MyApplication_Example, not the name of the project. In your example it will look like the following:

```
@testable import Pods_MyApplication_Example
```

And remove the import statement that imports the app target.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I still get the same error message after adding @testable.

Comment: Edit your question and provide the source code for your unit test class in the question. When editing your question also mention whether or not your project has a unit test target and show the steps you take to create the unit test class.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. I had to add the Plugin/Application that I want to test to the Test Target in my Podfile. So the Podfile looks like this:

```
use_frameworks!
target "MyApplication_tests" do
  pod 'MyApplication', :path => '../'
end
```

After running `pod update` I could then import and test my Application.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur when you don't have the correct test host appear.

If you see this, and you have selected the iOS Simulator or iPadOS simulator. Make sure that your test target supports that platform.

- Select the Xcode project in the lefthand browser.
- Click on your test target in the Project's General tab.
- Under "General" select your appropriate host application under
  "Testing".